# Аналитика сбоев в iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Занялся разработкой приложений для iOS и задался вопрос аналитики ошибок в приложении. Подключил Яндекс метрику, в сбоях приходят отчеты типа:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x1971d9e70

без указания метода или каких-то опознавательных названий, чтобы понять где была вызвана ошибка.

Собственно вопрос, это я что-то не так делаю? Или яндекс метрика просто не умеет получать необходимую информацию? Если можно посоветуйте сервис для получения сбоев от приложений на iOS.

Comment: эта ошибка не связана с аналитикой ошибок, просто runtime exception. где то в приложении вы хотите узнать length какого то объекта, а там сидит NSNull. начните с того, что в консоли сразу после ошибки напишите `po 0x1971d9e70` (адрес будет другим, просто скопируйте из ошибки). это вам покажет какой объект пытается это сделать. ну и дальше чудеса дебага :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший сервис для сбора ошибок - http://try.crashlytics.com/ Он показывает метод и номер строки, где упало приложение (если это возможно) + можно сделать пользовательскую информацию, которая будет прикрепляться к информации к падению

Answer (score 0):

Вероятность в 99.99% того, что где-то с сервера пришел null вместо пустой строки "" или вместо отсутствующего поля. Если у вас не используются поля с типом NSNull, то лучше из всех ответов с сервера это NSNull вырезать. Для этого есть много методов и категорий.

Если приложение уже в Аппсторе - добавьте проверку на сервер.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312879/removing-nulls-from-a-json-structure-recursively
https://gist.github.com/gintsmurans/5031198

Answer (score 0):

Мы в разработке своих приложений пользуемся сервисом аналитики  [UserX.pro](https://ru.userx.pro/)
у них существует тепловая карта касаний, Видеозапись пользовательских сессий, карты поведения пользователей + в сервисе обратная связь хорошая все рассказывают и подсказывают как делать, а самое главное большинство функций бесплатна! очень советую